# Run Script in VM Player from Windows 7

Tags: vmware-player, centos6.5

I have a VM player with CentOS 6.5. VM Player is installed in a Windows 7 PC.
CentOS has a root user and a normal user. I logged in as normal user.

I have a script file say "/test/mywork/autorun.sh" which I have to execute with root privilege.
I can run the script using `su root` inside the VM Player.

SO I want to know if there is any possibility that if I can send a trigger from windows 7 PC to VM Player to run the script? Something like I can trigger using the IP address of VM Player?

If not, then can I automatically execute the script as root without asking for password(pre-configure the password) while logging in as normal user ?

Comment: you can install and configure SSH access to the guest, and from windows write a script in whatever native langaguage to invoke putty, login to centos over ssh, and run a linux shell script (the linux script would just be a string inside the windows script, that you pass to putty for execution.)

Comment: Thanks Frank. Can we run the script as root even if we logged in to centos as normal user? also we have to configure SSH in both windows and centOS?